# How can I make ngx-easy-table responsive

Tags: angular, ngx-easy-table

Your table is very good. However one feature lacking which would help it be even better is having a responsive design.

Is there a way to do this in it current release?

Do you have any plans to add this capability in the near future?

Comment: This is the wrong place for this type of question. You should instead create an issue on the library's github location: https://github.com/ssuperczynski/ngx-easy-table

Comment: @Daniel W if you read the link on github form the author of ngx-easy-table, in his description on the subtitle questions  he/her clearly expresses that the questions regrading his/her project should be asked on stackoverflow using   ngx-easy-table tag.So please don't use the down vote without reading.

Comment: MichaelQ Please edit your post and add the ngx-easy-table tag so that the author may find your question easier

Answer (score -1):

I am not the author but i have some answers.

1.bootstrap 3 or 4 to make your table responsive an then use the appropriate classes on your table.

2. Learn css flexbox online and then your responsive design will become easier.

Answer (score -1):

Just apply Bootstrap class on the table tag:

```
   <ngx-table class="table-responsive"></ngx-table>
```